# Angular1/JavaScript - Improve algo condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have this condition which verifies the same property `labelKey` of an object `projectType` and return of different value according to the value of the property

```
checkProjectType () {
    if (this.projectType.labelKey === 'project_type.rent') {
      return 'geographical_area'
    } else if (this.projectType.labelKey === 'project_type.buying') {
      return 'geographical_area'
    } else {
      return 'address'
    }
  }
```

since there is too much resemblance in the condition how I refactored / optimized the condition with a simplified write using Lodash or ECMAScript 2015 for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also don't like `if-else-if…` chains, so prefer more readable variant.

```
function checkProjectType() {
    const defaultType = 'address';
    const key = this.projectType.labelKey;
    let map = {
        'project_type.rent': 'geographical_area',
        'project_type.buying': 'geographical_area'
    };

    return map[key] || defaultType;
}
```

`map` can be defined somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce this to less conditions as per your code.

```
checkProjectType () {
        var labelKey = this.projectType.labelKey;
        if (labelKey === 'project_type.rent' || labelKey === 'project_type.buying') {
          return 'geographical_area';
        }
       return 'address'; 
      }
```

Not sure what you want to do here with lodash

Answer (score 1):

Setting an if do X else if do X else do Y is wrong to me, you can simplify that in a single line : if (this.projectType.labelKey === 'project_type.rent' || this.projectType.labelKey === 'project_type.buying') would be easier to read already.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative way this could be written is using a `switch` statement:

```
switch (this.projectType.labelKey) {
case 'project_type.rent':
case 'project_type.buying':
    return 'geographical_area';
default:
    return 'address';
}
```

But one might argue it's a bit overkill in this case. Lodash or ECMAScript 2015 isn't going to do anything for you here.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the project type is included in an array of types, and use a ternary to select the response:

```
checkProjectType() {
  return ['project_type.rent', 'project_type.buying'].includes(this.projectType) ? 'geographical_area' : 'address';
}
```

If the types that produce `geographical_area`, you can refactored them out of the method (and the object/class):

```
const geoTypes = ['project_type.rent', 'project_type.buying'];

checkProjectType() {
  return geoTypes.includes(this.projectType) ? 'geographical_area' : 'address';
}
```